# How to check Firebase data success upload Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I check whether my data has been successfully pushed to Firebase?

I want to push my data like the picture

[image: Code Snipet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know when the write operation is completed or not, you need to use a complete listener. So let's say you want to know when the write operation for your `id_data` property is completed, please use the followig code:

```
addReference.child("DataInputManual").child(key).child("id_data").setValue(key)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //Do what you need to do
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

You can also use a success listener like this:

```
addReference.child("DataInputManual").child(key).child("id_data").setValue(key)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            //Do what you need to do
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you so much, but this method not working for me :

Comment: The fact that you encounter another problem, sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that I cannot responde in a comment or using only the the data above. As a personal guess, I think that is a UI problem but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Sorry about my words, but your answer very help me yesterday. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry about my words, but your answer very help me yesterday. Thank you very much

Comment: If it worked yesterday, should also work today, right?

Comment: yess, i dont know why my progressbar and my another view not show, when succsesfull push data to firebase? can you help me?

Comment: I've seen you have already accepted an answer. Does that answer solve your problem? I cannot understand how a code related to Firebase Storage can help you solve a Firebase real-time database issue...

Comment: As I said before, I think that is a UI problem but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: i have been accepted your answer sir. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check success or failure of upload on firebase Storage.

```
  final StorageReference photoRef =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("image_folder_on_firebase")
            .child("image_name" + ".jpeg");

    photoRef.putFile("local pic uri( Object of Uri)").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            newPicFirebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().getResult();


        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```